# Return different view, depends on caller view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have action which, update database. I can call it from two different views. I would like to return view A when view A call this funtion and return view B when view B call it. How to do that?

Comment: 1) You pass contextual information so the action can return the correct view. Or 2) You can move the shared code to a custom class -- we can call this a "service". Now each of your views can call different actions which can each return a specific view. These two actions will instantiate and call the shared code from the service rather than having an action call another action.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your business model new property

```
string action = Routing(model.First().Action);
return RedirectToAction(action);
```